# Can't initialize repository (mapped network drive)

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I've got a mapped network location "E:\folder\subfolder" where I have my project which I'd like to sync to github.

In VS code,

- clicking on "intialize repository",
- the command line ask a folder,
- the preset is fine (although manually browsing is the same)
- nothing happens

Doing the same procedure on
"C:\folder\subfolder": works just fine.

How to fix this?

I tried setting the permissions (which were already good, but tried 'full control' as well).
(mapped drive "E" is a NAS folder)

```
2022-11-06 19:15:18.574 [info] Validating found git in: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
2022-11-06 19:15:18.607 [info] Using git 2.38.1.windows.1 from C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
2022-11-06 19:15:18.696 [info] > git rev-parse --show-toplevel [83ms]
2022-11-06 19:15:18.696 [info] fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '//192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle'
'//192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle' is owned by:
    'S-1-5-21-2272522387-2785212326-2585521355-3048'
but the current user is:
    'S-1-5-21-3398360568-3200424794-839922802-1001'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

    git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle'
2022-11-06 19:15:18.746 [info] > git rev-parse --show-toplevel [46ms]
2022-11-06 19:15:18.746 [info] fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '//192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle'
'//192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle' is owned by:
    'S-1-5-21-2272522387-2785212326-2585521355-3048'
but the current user is:
    'S-1-5-21-3398360568-3200424794-839922802-1001'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

    git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle'
2022-11-06 19:15:18.799 [info] > git rev-parse --show-toplevel [50ms]
2022-11-06 19:15:18.800 [info] fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '//192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle/pyfiddle.extension'
'//192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle/pyfiddle.extension' is owned by:
    'S-1-5-21-2272522387-2785212326-2585521355-3048'
but the current user is:
    'S-1-5-21-3398360568-3200424794-839922802-1001'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

    git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle/pyfiddle.extension'
2022-11-06 19:15:18.833 [info] > git rev-parse --show-toplevel [31ms]
2022-11-06 19:15:18.833 [info] fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '//192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle'
'//192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle' is owned by:
    'S-1-5-21-2272522387-2785212326-2585521355-3048'
but the current user is:
    'S-1-5-21-3398360568-3200424794-839922802-1001'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

    git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle'
2022-11-06 19:15:18.886 [info] > git rev-parse --show-toplevel [50ms]
2022-11-06 19:15:18.886 [info] fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '//192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle'
'//192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle' is owned by:
    'S-1-5-21-2272522387-2785212326-2585521355-3048'
but the current user is:
    'S-1-5-21-3398360568-3200424794-839922802-1001'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

    git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle'
2022-11-06 19:15:18.963 [info] > git rev-parse --show-toplevel [41ms]
2022-11-06 19:15:18.963 [info] fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '//192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle'
'//192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle' is owned by:
    'S-1-5-21-2272522387-2785212326-2585521355-3048'
but the current user is:
    'S-1-5-21-3398360568-3200424794-839922802-1001'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

    git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle'
2022-11-06 19:15:53.100 [info] > git rev-parse --show-toplevel [108ms]
2022-11-06 19:15:53.100 [info] fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '//192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle/pyfiddle.extension'
'//192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle/pyfiddle.extension' is owned by:
    'S-1-5-21-2272522387-2785212326-2585521355-3048'
but the current user is:
    'S-1-5-21-3398360568-3200424794-839922802-1001'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

    git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle/pyfiddle.extension'
2022-11-06 19:16:19.893 [info] > git rev-parse --show-toplevel [46ms]
2022-11-06 19:16:19.893 [info] fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '//192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle/pyfiddle.extension'
'//192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle/pyfiddle.extension' is owned by:
    'S-1-5-21-2272522387-2785212326-2585521355-3048'
but the current user is:
    'S-1-5-21-3398360568-3200424794-839922802-1001'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

    git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle/pyfiddle.extension'
2022-11-06 19:16:34.246 [info] > git rev-parse --show-toplevel [47ms]
2022-11-06 19:16:34.246 [info] fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '//192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle/pyfiddle.extension'
'//192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle/pyfiddle.extension' is owned by:
    'S-1-5-21-2272522387-2785212326-2585521355-3048'
but the current user is:
    'S-1-5-21-3398360568-3200424794-839922802-1001'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

    git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle/pyfiddle.extension'
2022-11-06 19:16:40.597 [info] > git rev-parse --show-toplevel [90ms]
2022-11-06 19:16:40.597 [info] fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '//192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle/pyfiddle.extension'
'//192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle/pyfiddle.extension' is owned by:
    'S-1-5-21-2272522387-2785212326-2585521355-3048'
but the current user is:
    'S-1-5-21-3398360568-3200424794-839922802-1001'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

    git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle/pyfiddle.extension'
2022-11-06 19:16:40.633 [info] > git rev-parse --show-toplevel [33ms]
2022-11-06 19:16:40.633 [info] fatal: detected dubious ownership in repository at '//192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle/pyfiddle.extension'
'//192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle/pyfiddle.extension' is owned by:
    'S-1-5-21-2272522387-2785212326-2585521355-3048'
but the current user is:
    'S-1-5-21-3398360568-3200424794-839922802-1001'
To add an exception for this directory, call:

    git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///192.168.2.151/Google Drive __ pyfiddle/github test/py_fiddle/pyfiddle.extension'
```

Comment: @lapourganger I've added my log in my post

Comment: You could list all of these as "safe" directories or fix the ownership issues, but in general it's a terrible, awful, no-good, very bad idea to put a Git repository on this kind of "drive" because you will find the repository gets corrupted, probably just before a big deadline.

Answer (score 0):

Show us your git log:

- Type `Ctrl + Maj + P` (As the same time), a typebox open
- Type `Terminal: Focus on Terminal View`
- Go to `Output` tab
- In the dropdown list select `Git`

Copy an paste the content